# Google chrome published test extension "Install on browser access error"

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I had published our extension for testing but our team can't install it show "Access error" message, how can I test it? Thanks.

Comment: Please post any error-logs and include keywords from question tag in your question to get in context.

Comment: Make sure you're uploading a zip, not a crx.

Comment: _"I had published our extension for testing"_ And what precisely do you mean by that? What are the publishing settings?